# Game Multi-Images Android

Tags: android, png, assets

I have seen a lot of developer use all asset or images or drawable needed into one file png like this :

[image]

- the question is how can developer split each image to use it in android ?
- and what's advantage of this technique ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is mainly used in game development, and the file you linked is called a Texture Atlas.

It's main advantage is that the game engine has to load only one texture which saves a lot of memory writing, making the game run smoother.

Splitting is normally done with the help of an XML/JSON file which contains the coordinates and size of every image, that way the engine knows where each image is located in the atlas.

You can find more information about Texture Atlases [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas)